# In a Feature spec, set the user with Warden for redirects in actions in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warden

I'm able to get faked authenticated feature specs (via `rspec`) to work with my application using `login_as` which covers the *next* request to occur. However, for actions that contain redirects with the Rails controller's action, it does not appear possible to set the user proxy in place for *that* request (the redirection). Is there a way to tell the application to use `login_as` for all requests in a feature spec?

Answer (score 1):

So, [this old GitHub thread comment](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/issues/99#issuecomment-71298863) appears to have a solution that still works from in my initial testing.

```rb
module Warden
  module Test
    module Helpers

      def login_permanently_as(user, opts = {})
        Warden::Manager.on_request do |proxy|
          opts[:event] || :authentication
          proxy.set_user(user, opts)
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Monkey patch `Warden::Test::Helpers` to add a method which makes use of `on_request`. Now in my Capybara feature specs I no longer need to constantly set `login_as` for every click to a new page and it is set for those actions which have redirects as part of the execution.

Comment: It appears that this method doesn't persist session data, so if you are trying to reach into session data after a redirect within a controller, it won't have that data from before the redirect

Comment: Was able to use `proxy.env['rack.session']` to set session values (essentially mock them). `Warden::Proxy` has some other methods for setting session, but none of them worked except this one.